# How to create Android Layout dynamically in separate class other than class that extends Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have an activity class that has linear layout with vertical orientation with TextView.
Now I need to add an layout to this layout dynamically .Currently I have an activity named MainActivity. Now I need to create a class that returns Layout which does not extend Activity.Is there a  way in which I can do this .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I could not understand what you are asking.  If you carefully rewrite your question you might get more responses.  What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to make the screen change dynamically (change while the program is running)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extend the layout type you need and have it build the layout you want.

```
public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout {......}
```